# Link to a facebook application from a facebook page does not work?

Tags: facebook

I have a ready facebook application that should be linked to a facebook page. I am trying to link the canvas url of my application to a button in the page with the help of javascript by calling:

```
function onBtnClick() { window.location = "http://apps.facebook.com/CANVAS_URL/"; }
```

When I click the button that is supposed to take me to the app I get only an empty page with a blue box and "Facebook" string inside it (pretty much looking like the facebook logo)

This box is a link to my application and if clicked takes me to `http://apps.facebook.com/CANVAS_URL/`

The same problem occurs in the application, where I try to link the facebook page. The link there is a regular `<a>` tag.

Do you have any ideas how to redirect to an app without this additional "Facebook" page?

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
top.location.href = "http://apps.facebook.com/CANVAS_URL/";
```

You need the upper frame (Facebook) to redirect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. 
Sorry for bothering with this stupid question

Answer (score 0):

If using a simple `<a>` html link, try `target="_top"`